# How do we know what cshtml files will have changes reflected immediately if edits have been made on IIS hosted applications?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

In my .NET MVC application which i have hosted on an IIS server, it appears that only some `.cshtml` view files will reflect changes immediately in a browser if a simple HTML change was made. While others dont seem to reflect immediately.

How can we know what files will have changes reflected immediately? At the moment, it appears that anything in the "shared" folder in the views folder will update straight away, while those in other folders i have added myself do not have the same behaviour..

If i want to make a change to a cshtml view file on the server, how can i ensure that the changes will reflect immediately? Is there a way to do it without restarting the app pool?

Answer (score 0):

Site-specific change:

Explicitly setting the HttpRuntimeSection.FcnMode property under ‘Web.config’ for site-specific setting.
Example:

System-wide change :
Change the DWORD registry setting for HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode to the value 0, which will enable all file change notifications.

For cache issue, you could use iis HTTP header keep alive option.

you could follow the below steps:

1) Open IIS Manager and select the site from the connection pane.

2)Double-click on the HTTP Response Headers

[image]

3)Click Set Common Headers… from the action pane:

[image]

4)Check the Enable HTTP keep-alive checkbox, Check the box to expire Web content and select immediately radio button.

[image]